# Arduino smells burnt but works fine, what shall I do?

Tags: arduino

My Arduino Nano is on a stripboard which provides a convenient access to some pins. It is connected to two I2C devices. The power supply comes from the USB port. It worked yesterday.

Today I plugged it to one of the USB ports of my PC. The power LED lit up for a split second and then the LED went off. I could smell something had burnt. My USB ports are surge protected: if a device draws too much current the USB power supply should shut down.

I unplugged everything and tested in the following order:

- All the USB ports of my computer work with other USB devices
- The Arduino alone powers on
- The Arduino can send serial data through USB
- The Arduino powers on when connected to the stripboard
- I can upload sketches to the Arduino
- The Arduino can send data coming from the first I2C device through USB
- The Arduino can send data coming from the second I2C device through USB
- The Arduino can send data coming from both I2C devices at the same time through USB

The last test is exactly the same setup as when I experienced the issue. It now seems to work again. Visual inspection did not reveal any burnt component or tracks on the Arduino or the I2C devices. The smell seems to come from the Arduino.

Questions:

- Can there be a smell without any actual damage?
- What might have been the problem?
- What tests I should run to check for hidden issues?

First question here, thanks for reading :)

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong without schematics and good pictures of your circuit. It may be a jumper that is touching another contact or maybe you're working over a metalic surface and that is shorting contacts in the bottom layer of your board.

Comment: As for the smell, you must have definitely hurt a device. It may continue to work for who knows how long, but you probably have shortened its life. In any case you've been much luckier than I have. I've burned three ATmega328P just like that! No fireworks, no smell.

Comment: @Ricardo: My circuit isn't doing anything apart from breaking out pins conveniently. It doesn't contain any component. The metallic surface shorting contacts is a possibility.

Comment: Maybe you shorted +3V3 output to ground on your board. That forced high current through the onboard regulator that shut down. That could explain the behaviour you reported (power LED light up for a split second then going off). That wouldn't damage the MCU, only the regulator, which may continue to work or not. One thing to watch out for is when you connect a board like nano onto a breadboard in a way that the board hides the connections. In some cases you may connect pins in short without knowing, if you miss the right strip on the breadboard. That's how I lost one of my MCUs.

Comment: The short is gone. It either burned, opening a short. Or it was removed. I often have such encounters. Where either the Plastic of the Chip is heated or a wire trace and the solder mask is heated. Where they off gas. This makes you appreciate the need to have spares. As this may be problematic or just keep going. I personally like Ricardo's possibility of a short between the regulator and GND. The USB will constrain the supply to just before popping the linear regulator.

Comment: Interesting comments from everybody. As far as I understand there are 2 regulators on the board: one for the 3.3V supply, and one for the Vin input. I use neither of them at the moment (the I2C is on 5V) so they could have burnt without me noticing. I will try measuring the resistance between the ground and the 3.3V and Vin pins. If it reads 0V or infinity I know where the damage is! I will keep you updated.

Comment: I have no 0 ohm or infinity resistance anywhere. I just ordered another similar Arduino Nano board to compare it with.

Comment: The resistances between the pins and the ground are the same on the new board and the "broken" one except for the 3.3V. However the 3.3V does what it should on both boards. Puzzling :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was **unanswerable** *four years ago* and it is still **unanswerable** today.

Answer (score 2):

You probably hurt something. But keep using it until it dies. :-)
Did you try to power it from a non-USB source? You could have done some damage to your voltage regulator.

I recently burned a trace on my board. It popped right out of the board, let out the magic smoke, and made me scared I had fried the whole thing. One bus wire soldered to the right place, and I'm back in business. Pictures of the issue and the fix are [here](http://thecoldheartofspace.blogspot.com/2014/01/flight-controller-oops.html). Good luck.

Comment: your link is now broken.

Comment: @shredalert Updated. I let the domain expire, apparently. :-)

Comment: glad it's back up again! :)